# Static web page with Symfony MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony1

I'am new to symfony.

I need to build a static web page. The page simply contains a form but it could be any othe content: however the content is static.

The symfony documentation describes this pattern for user request handling:

user http request -> symfony router match the correct route (controller + action) -> an action on the controller is executed -> the action generate the http response

This is of course a valid pattern for handling requests that need to take data from database etc (non-static content)

For static content the action on the controller will always generate the same http response.

So for static content is there a way in symfony to access the static page without passing through the controller?

I know I can place a static html under the document root folder tree, but this seems not to be a symfony best-practice, does it??

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you said about 1.4 Symfony, you can use **[this](http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HowtoServeStaticContent)** method for static page. Or you can

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say that i'm using Symfony2. Does this work also in Symfony2 ? it seems to solve my question!

Comment: I use Symfony 1.4, maybe it works in symfony 2, but unfortunately I do not now Symfony 2, so I can not help you in this case:-(

Answer (score 1):

Create a static bundle as in Liip blog post and keep your static contents there. I don't think when a request comes to a controller it should interact with Model .

Controller is just the starting point. Models doesn't need to be be connections with Database also. It can be some logic. Good if you read the quick start of 5 minutes.

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/page_creation.html

http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2011/05/19/symfony2-bundle-structure-a-use-case.html

Comment: I have already red the complete symfony 2 guide. My question is: I have to serve a static content. I do not need any business logic to be run: so do i need to manage the user request through a controller anyway? or i can do it without passing through the controller? Actually the StaticBundle in the Liip blog post uses a controller to serve static content...

Comment: Yes you need a controller. Else place it as html in the public folder, so you don't need controller then :).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the FrameworkBundle:Template:template controller as explained in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html)